# Collapsing columns sharing unique value (s) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, aggregate, unique

How can I collapse columns of rows, giving that they share unique values?

I have a data frame like this:

```
Group   Status  Temperature     Ref
A       Moving                  1   
A               Cold            1   
B       Static                  1   
B               Warm            2   
C       Static  Temperate       3   
C               Temperate       3
```

And my desired output is

```
Group   Status  Temperature     Ref
A       Moving  Cold            1   
B       Static  Warm            1;2
C       Static  Temperate       3
```

It's supposedly simple, but when I did

```
aggregate(df$Temperature, list(df$Group), paste, collapse=",")
```

or

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Temperature=paste(Temperature, collapse=''))
```

I only partial columns, depending on which columns I selected.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(Status, Temperature), list(~ifelse(.=="", NA, .))) %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    fill(Status, Temperature, .direction = "downup") %>% 
    group_by(Group, Status, Temperature) %>%
    unique %>% 
    summarise(Ref = paste(Ref, collapse = ";"))
```

Caveat: this code turns empty values in `Status` and `Temperature` into NA first, and then fills the value assuming that for each `Group` there is only one value for `Status` and `Temperature`.

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty close indeed, but what about if there are some different values for Status and Temperature? I just checked my data and there indeed are different values..

Comment: Then could you clarify what you want the code to do? (Maybe update the sample dataframe and the desired output)

Comment: Also please provide the dataframe in a reproducible format! (i.e. `df <- data.frame(Group = ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply join all non-blanks and `unique` values only using `summarise(across(...`

Do it like this

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ toString(unique(.[. != '']))))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Group Status Temperature Ref  
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>       <chr>
1 A     Moving Cold        1    
2 B     Static Warm        1, 2 
3 C     Static Temperate   3
```

dput(df) used was

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Status = c("Moving", 
"", "Static", "", "Static", ""), Temperature = c("", "Cold", 
"", "Warm", "Temperate", "Temperate"), Ref = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```